# how to use external jquery plugin in react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I've built a **React** project using **CRA**. I need to use a plugin that is built using **jquery**. It's a datepicker but the calendar it's using is Bikram Sambat. The link to the datepicker code is [Nepali Date Picker](https://github.com/leapfrogtechnology/Nepali-Date-Picker) . I've done the following:

**public/index.html**

```
<link href="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/nepaliDatePicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="%PUBLIC_URL%/assets/nepaliDatePicker.min.js"></script>
```

**NepaliDate Component**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const $ = window.$;

export default class NepaliDate extends Component {
    shouldComponentUpdate() {
        return false;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        $('.date-picker').nepaliDatePicker({
            dateFormat: '%D, %M %d, %y',
            closeOnDateSelect: true
        });
    }
    showDatePicker = () => {
        $('.date-picker').nepaliDatePicker();
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <input
                type="text"
                value=""
                name="date"
                className="date-picker"
                onFocus={this.showDatePicker}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

The datepicker isn't showing up.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Nothing on the console. But the `input` gets disabled after clicking on it. When I console.log something on the ** showDatePicker** function, it logs for the first time.

Comment: Your code works for me. It shows up the datepicker when I click on it.

Comment: really? Let me try creating a new project and test it :).

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara it's working on a new project. Might be the `z-index` or `position` issue with my current project style. Thank you so much for pointing that out for me.

Comment: wow this is works for me, thanks.. btw how did you find it using window.$ is it documented? @TusharKhatiwada

Answer (score 0):

Can use "react-load-script" to load 3rd part JS libraries. After install can use like below
import Script from 'react-load-script'

```
render(){
return(
<div>
 <Script url="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"/>
            <Script url="menu.js"/>
//.....Remaining code can be here

</div>

);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just follow instruction showed on Nepali-Date-Picker github page, install library with npm install and add CDN link to your html file inside public folder inside head element above root element, hope this resolve your issue.